# How to return Json rather than a string in Web Api

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-web-api

I tried to look through some links but didn't work for me but this is what I have:

```
[HttpGet]
public string GetTimes()
{
    var varCheck = checkUser();

    if (varCheck.Item1)
    {
        using (SqlConnection sc = new SqlConnection(connectionTest))
        {
            try
            {
                sc.Open();

                using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("GetTheTimes", sc))
                {
                    sda.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    sda.Fill(ds);

                    foreach (DataTable table in ds.Tables)
                    {
                        foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
                        {
                            listItems.Add(new DataCheck
                            {
                                var1 = row["var1"].ToString(),
                                var2 = row["var2"].ToString()
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (SqlException sqe)
            {
                return "There was an error with retrieving the data, please try again later";
            }
            finally
            {
                sc.Close();
            }
        }

        var jsonSerialier = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var json = jsonSerialier.Serialize(listItems);

        return json;
    }
    else
    {
        return "Failed";
    }
}
```

When the API is called it is returned with escape double quotes. How can I modify so it returns a pure Json Object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
[HttpGet]
//to prevent conflict with HttpGet use inline namespacing
public System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult GetTimes()
{
    return new System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult { Data = result };
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Do I still have to use the JavaScriptSerializer function or not anymore?

Comment: It will just serialize automagically no matter what type you put into the Data property of JsonResult

Comment: Thank you. I didn't have to serialize anymore. Also I did try that before but I had to locally use System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult rather than import the namespace which caused a whole bunch of other issue. I should've tried a little harder before posting the question so I didn't get a -2. Thanks for the help.

Comment: No problem. I did a +1. Can you please mark it as answered.

Comment: I like how you said it will `serialize autoMAGICALLY`... which is absolutely the case ;)